# .NET 4.8 - WCF Complex Schema - Presenting derived types as the base using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf

I am having major issues consuming a SOAP service with a complex schema due to inheritance

I have a base type `ProcessMessage`

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(ProcessCustomerMessage))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.8.3928.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public abstract class ProcessMessage
{

}
```

I then have multiple derived types such as `ProcessCustomerMessage` `ProcessRepairMessage` which inherit the base.

The issue is that i need to present the derived types as the base in order for the service to accept it

I have followed what documentation i can and added `XmlInclude` and `XmlType` where required...

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(TypeName = "ProcessMessage", AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.mynamespace.org")]
public class ProcessCustomerMessage: ProcessMessage {

  private ProcessCustomerInformationPayload payloadField;

  /// <remarks/>
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
  public ProcessCustomerInformationPayload payload {
    get {
      return this.payloadField;
    }
    set {
      this.payloadField = value;
    }
  }
}
```

The above code will serialize correctly but the service rejects it with the following error

`Unknown type {tran:ProcessMessage} specified in xsi:type attribute`

This is because of `xsi:type="tran:ProcessMessage"` in the Xml

```
<tran:ProcessMessage xsi:type="tran:ProcessMessage" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

I cannot see how to remove this `xsi:type` from the Xml

I am using XmlSerializer not DCS as the schema is so complex its not supported by DCS, i also have no control over the schema as its a 3rd party service.

Comment: The xsi:type is put into xml when a class inherits a base class.  So you need to have an XMLInclude.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute?view=net-5.0

Comment: hi @jdweng i have that on the base here `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(ProcessCustomerMessage))]` 

Are you saying i need it on the derived? can you give an example of what you mean? 

Thanks

Comment: i have tried removing the XmlType("ProcessMessage") from the derived but i get `<tran:ProcessMessage xsi:type="tran:ProcessCustomerMessage" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">` 

xsi:type cannot be in the payload at all for the service to accept it, its so close....

Comment: You are backwards.  The XmlInclude goes before the Base Class, has the types of the inherited classes, and do not need namespace.

Comment: @jdweng sorry im not following, the xmlinclude is on the Base class `ProcessMessage` see above

Comment: Should this line be ProcessCustomerMessage  : [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(TypeName = "ProcessMessage", AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.mynamespace.org")]